# module override issue in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, overriding, magento-1.8

Hi all and thanks for reading,
I'm using magento with plugin which extends

> Core/Store

using the model

> Plugin/Store

model. Now it's time to extend this plugin and update the module functions, so I want to override

> Plugin/Store

model by my custom model

> Custom/Store

so tell now the over all view should end as the following:

> Core/Store ---- overridden by ---> Plugin/Store ---- overridden by
>   ---> Custom/Store

but if I call `Mage::getModel('Core/Store');`, I get instance of

> Plugin/Store

model. that is because magento is reading Core module configurations and it finds that Core/Store model is overridden by Plugin/Store without checking if Plugin/Store is overridden by any other model (which is Custom/Store in my case).
this means all `Mage::getModel('Core/Store');` in all magneto code will not return

> Custom/Store

instance and will not use the new developed functionality.
Am I saying right or there is a way to make it work?

PS: in my case even after overriding Plugin/Store by Custom/Store:

> 1- the call `Mage::app()` will return an object has _stores array and
>   all stores in it are  Plugin/Store instance.

```
2- the call `Mage::getModel('Plugin/Store');` will return Custom/Store instance
```

> 3- the call `Mage::getModel('Core/Store');` will return Plugin/Store
>   instance

Answer (score 1):

**Dependency between modules**

1) When extending a Magento core module, dependency between modules needs to be configured

e.g. `app/etc/modules/MyNamespace_Customer.xml:`

```
<MyNamespace_Customer>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>local</codePool>
    <priority>1</priority>
    <depends>
        <Mage_Customer/>
    </depends>
</MyNamespace_Customer>
```

2) When creating an `SQL` installer or data installer in the Custom Module that updates the Magento core module entity, a dependency needs to be created

e.g. installer in `MyCustomModule`:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$sqlQuote = 'ALTER TABLE ' . $this->getTable('sales_flat_quote') .
            ' ADD `is_urgent` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0';

$installer->run($sqlOrder);
$installer->run($sqlQuote);

$installer->endSetup();
```

e.g. `dependency config` (sales quote entity is altered, dependency with ‘Sales’ module needs to be added):

```
<MyNamespace_MyCustomModule>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>local</codePool>
    <priority>1</priority>
    <depends>
        <Mage_Sales/>
    </depends>
</MyNamespace_MyCustomModule>
```

3) `Extending/Rewriting a file (model, helper, block, controller)` from the Magento core module requires dependency between modules, otherwise the last changed version will be arbitrary and you will lose control over the rewrite.

Module dependencies are important to prioritize order of `SQL` statements, and on a fresh install they will avoid conflicts, crashes or wrong final data.

Based on above, you can define your dependency between modules `Plugin/Store` and `Custom/Store`.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer, but I have added dependency between the new custom module and plugin module (e.g `<depends>
        <new_plugin/>
    </depends>` in custom module configuration)

Comment: It should go something like this
`Plugin/Store` depends on `Core/Store` and `Custom/Store` depends on `Plugin/Store`

Comment: that's exactly what it is now, but still same as I explained in my question.

Comment: While installing modules you have to make sure they are compatible with each other. Sometime you have to modify as needed.